# FluentNhibernate C# mapping an XML-file?

Tags: c#, xml, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Is there anyway to map FluentNhibernate against an XML-file..instead of a database?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you wanna do this... nhibernate can't save to XML files, so fluent*NHibernate* probably isn't what you really need.

The answer is no, you can't use fluentNHibernate to help you on this.